# How will I test my private methods in ios?

Tags: tdd

I am developing an app in ios5 using tdd, how  should I test a private method.

Comment: question is: should you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either be satisfied with testing the public interface OR use a reflection mechanism of some kind to gain backdoor access to private methods in your tests.

I'm a Java developer; that's what I do.